# Open a script on workspace with just a link

Tags: python, html

Automater sends out an automated e-mail message that contains several links.

The links provided will call a script with different command line arguments depending on which link they clicked on.

So for example an e-mail would look like this:

- Zipped contents located at this link \\intranet\nightbuild: **click1**
- Click on this link unpack all compressed files into your C:\somedirectory  **clicky2**
- Click on this link to unpack this (somezip) file into your C:\somedirectory **clicky3**

This is all done on outlook.

```
<a href="file:///C:/users/nickb/desktop/somepython.py">Click me!</a>
```

That's what I tried, but instead it just opens up the python script and I see its contents.

Comment: Does that computer have a Python interpreter setup to run `py` files by default?

Comment: Yes it does. It seems more like an html thing since I tried doing it with a batch file as well and I just end up seeing its contents instead of it running.

Comment: So if you copy a `py` file to your desktop and then double-click it, it runs through a Python interpreter?

Comment: are we talking >>> interpreter or do I see the python do whats its suppose to in the cmd? Because I just have it print hello and then wait until input. And it does that when I click it.

Comment: If you copy a `py` file to your desktop and double-click, does it do anything like what you expect?

Comment: Are you running Windows 7 and Outlook by any chance?

Comment: Yep I am running both of those.

Comment: Check the *Default Programs* from the *Start* menu. Outlook can act different in the way it handles default behavior.

Comment: Well i'm currently testing the script through html and avoiding outlook completely for now.

Comment: Well, you could easily work around this issue if you used a server setup to run `py` files and not use a `file:///` link. FYI. Otherwise, it's up to how the current computer is setup and whether or not it allows you to run a `py` file locally or as text.

Answer (score 0):

Opening links it Microsoft Outlook automatically open the file in the correct manner, however, I still had one problem, according to this  [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/i-can-t-use-html-tags-in-html-e-mail-messages-HA010199144.aspx). Microsoft outlook does NOT allow you edit html in the outlook viewer, it follows the WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) philosophy.

Thus all html must be handled by python in the MIME header. If using the smtplib from python follow this [link](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html#email-examples) and scroll to the bottom. The example is shown there.

NOTE: you have to include the MIMEText, and MIMEMultipart to handle smtp headers.

Thank you all for your help.